# How to annotate a broken_barh chart while hovering?

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I am trying to plot the Gantt chart using matplotlib in python, wherein there are two solutions suggested by different algorithms. Solution by each algorithm contains a group of batches (shown in different colors) starting and finishing at different points of time.

I am able to plot the same, but I want to annotate the graph in such a way that whenever I hover the mouse over the solution, it shows batch detail or length of the bar (processing time). I tried several ways, but not happening. [I would like to see (x,y)= (Batch Processing Time, Algorithm Name) value when I move the mouse over the batch solution.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

%matplotlib notebook
  
 
fig, gnt = plt.subplots() 
gnt.set_ylim(0, 50)
gnt.set_xlim(0, 65) 
 
    
# Setting labels for x-axis and y-axis 
gnt.set_xlabel('Batch Completion Time') 
gnt.set_ylabel('Solution by') 
  
# Setting ticks on y-axis 
gnt.set_yticks([10, 25])
gnt.set_yticklabels(['Algo_1', 'Algo_2']) 

# Setting graph attribute 
gnt.grid(True) 

     
#For Algo-1 Solution
gnt.broken_barh([(5,9), (14,1) , (15,4) , (19,9) , (28,4) , (34,4) , (38,5)],(5, 10),\
                facecolors = {'tab:blue','tab:red', 'tab:olive', 'tab:pink', 'tab:cyan', 'tab:brown', 'tab:orange'})
    

#For Algo-2 Solution
gnt.broken_barh([(14,6), (22,4) , (29,7) , (36,3) , (39,15)],(20,10),\
                facecolors = {'tab:blue','tab:red', 'tab:olive', 'tab:pink', 'tab:cyan'})
    
#upto here Gantt Chart is drawn
#Process of showing data while moving the mouse over the chart


annot = gnt.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,30),textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="black", ec="b", lw=2),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))

annot.set_visible(False)

def update_annot(bar):
    
    x = bar.get_x() + bar.get_width()
    y = bar.get_y()+  (0.5*bar.get_height())
    
    annot.xy = (x,y) #box no (x,y) cordinate update karse
    text = "{:.2g},{:.2g}".format(x,y)
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.9)  

    
def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == gnt:
        for bar in gnt:
            cont, ind = bar.contains(event)
            if cont:
                update_annot(bar)
                annot.set_visible(True)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()
                return
    if vis:
        annot.set_visible(False)
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)

plt.show()
```

[image: I would like to see (x,y)= (Batch Processing Time, Algorithm Name) value when I move hover the over the batch solution.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** The code has been adapted to change the box's position when close to the borders. That way, the annotation stays better visible inside the plot. (Unfortunately, `mplcursors` doesn't work with `broken_barh`.)

`broken_barh` doesn't create individual bars, but one big `BrokenBarHCollection` object.
When `contains(event)` is called, either `False` or `True` is returned, together with the index telling which of the small bars has been clicked on.

With `.get_paths()[ind].get_extents()` one can get the bounding box of that small bar. The coordinates of the bounding box lead to the start time and the duration.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def update_annot(brokenbar_collection, coll_id, ind, x, y):
    annot.xy = (x, y)
    box = brokenbar_collection.get_paths()[ind].get_extents()
    text = f"{ax_gnt.get_yticklabels()[coll_id].get_text()} index:{ind} duration:{box.x1 - box.x0:.0f} "
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.8)
    xpos, ypos = annot.get_position()
    if x > xmax - (xmax - xmin) * 0.3:
        annot.set(position=(-20, ypos), anncoords="offset points", horizontalalignment='right')
    elif x < xmin + (xmax - xmin) * 0.3:
        annot.set(position=(20, ypos), anncoords="offset points", horizontalalignment='left')

    xpos, ypos = annot.get_position()
    if y > ymax - (ymax - ymin) * 0.3:
        annot.set(position=(xpos, -30), anncoords="offset points", verticalalignment='top')
    elif y < ymin + (ymax - ymin) * 0.3:
        annot.set(position=(xpos, 30), anncoords="offset points", verticalalignment='bottom')

def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax_gnt:
        for coll_id, brokenbar_collection in enumerate(ax_gnt.collections):
            cont, ind = brokenbar_collection.contains(event)
            if cont:
                update_annot(brokenbar_collection, coll_id, ind['ind'][0], event.xdata, event.ydata)
                annot.set_visible(True)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()
                return
    if vis:
        annot.set_visible(False)
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig, ax_gnt = plt.subplots()
ymin, ymax = 0, 35
ax_gnt.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
xmin, xmax = 0, 65
ax_gnt.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)

ax_gnt.set_yticks([10, 25])
ax_gnt.set_yticklabels(['Algo_1', 'Algo_2'])

ax_gnt.grid(True)

# For Algo-1 Solution
ax_gnt.broken_barh([(5, 9), (14, 1), (15, 4), (19, 9), (28, 4), (34, 4), (38, 5)], (5, 10),
                   facecolors={'tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:olive', 'tab:pink', 'tab:cyan', 'tab:brown', 'tab:orange'})
# For Algo-2 Solution
ax_gnt.broken_barh([(14, 6), (22, 4), (29, 7), (36, 3), (39, 15)], (20, 10),
                   facecolors={'tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:olive', 'tab:pink', 'tab:cyan'})

annot = ax_gnt.annotate("", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(20, 30), textcoords="offset points",
                        bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="yellow", ec="b", lw=2),
                        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: I have integrated figure containing broken_barh chart in tkinter window. The issue which I am facing is when I am moving the mouse near the center of the plot then I am able to perfectly see my annotation box. But when I am moving the cursor near the extreme edges of the plot/figure the annotation box is getting blocked by the tkinter window. Can you suggest how to solve this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you post a working example of above using mplcursors. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution is working for me. From your updated code I understand that you have put conditions in only x-direction. What would be the changes if we want to limit both in x & y direction both.

Comment: I have independently given y-axis limits like you have given for x-axis. But it's not working

Comment: @RRSC I don't understand.  I just tried it, and it works. See the updated code.

Comment: I was trying with wrong limits that's why it was not working. Thanks for your suggestion. Now it's working.

Comment: I was trying to integrate the broken_barh plot in tkinter window where with the help of your initial answer I was unable to see annotation box fully. That's why I was asking for changes.

Answer (score 0):

The JohanC , you saved my day ... there is a small correction required if using pyqt5

```
                sc.axes.broken_barh([(h[0][xc]["start"],h[0][xc]["interval"])], (h[0][xc]["id"], 0.5), facecolors =(u))
                annot = sc.axes.annotate(str(h[0][xc]["interval"]), xy=(h[0][xc]["start"],h[0][xc]["id"]), xytext=(20, 30), textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="yellow", ec="b", lw=2),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
                annot.set_visible(False)
                def update_annot(brokenbar_collection, coll_id, ind, x, y):
                    annot.xy = (x, y)
                    box = brokenbar_collection.get_paths()[ind].get_extents()
                    text = f"{sc.axes.get_yticklabels()[coll_id].get_text()} index:{ind} duration:{box.x1 - box.x0:.0f} "
                    annot.set_text(text)
                    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.9)

                def hover(event):
                    vis = annot.get_visible()
                    print("####",sc.axes.collections)
                    print("###",event.inaxes)
                    if event.inaxes == sc.axes:
                        print
                        for coll_id, brokenbar_collection in enumerate(sc.axes.collections):
                            cont, ind = brokenbar_collection.contains(event)
                            if cont:
                                update_annot(brokenbar_collection, coll_id, ind['ind'][0], event.xdata, event.ydata)
                                annot.set_visible(True)
                                sc.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
                                return
                    if vis:
                        annot.set_visible(False)
                        sc.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
                sc.figure.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)
```